# Getting error "PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException", "Class 'app\models\Yii' not found" while executing query in yii2

Tags: yii2-basic-app

I have just created on basic example for fetching of data from table using [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-databases.html) and it worked well, but now I want to write query using yii query builder

```
($list= Yii::$app()->db->createCommand('select * from country')->queryAll();)
```

but in this case I am getting error for

> "PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException", "Class 'app\models\Yii' not found".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model is not properly `namespace` [Read PHP Namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Change Your Query Code as

```
$list= \Yii::$app()->db->createCommand('select * from country')->queryAll();
```

Change Your Country Model as

```
class Country extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
```

{

```
public static function getAllCountry()
{
    $list = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select * from country')->queryAll();
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($list);
    die;
}
```

}

and to get list from Your Controller:

```
\app\models\Country::getAllCountry();
```

Comment: Thanks! A lot. I appreciate you. It makes my day.